# Is it possible to loop just one part of the timeline?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Here is a screenshot of what I'm working with at the moment...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/45GX9.png
The area that I've outlined in red shows the frames that I want to loop after the rest of the animation has stopped. The ActionScript in the layer above is simply a `stop();` command for the whole animation.
The two layers that I need to loop are a tweening 'highlight' and the relevant mask to fit it to the type below.

Comment: Just convert the frames in question into a new MovieClip.

Comment: It won't let me, this is the timeline for a MovieClip.

Comment: You could always cut & paste the frames.  Also, on your screenshot, the layers are locked - perhaps that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for whatever reason you can't or don't want to create a looping movieClip you could simply change the `stop();` command to `gotoAndPlay(70);`

Comment: Agree, but I'll use labels instead of frame numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just put whatever animation you want to happen into its own movie clip. Movie clips can be nested as deep as you like. To control your looping movieclip just give it an instance name and then you can call:

```
instance name.start()
```

...or...

```
instance name.stop()
```

...from wherever you are putting your actions.